# How to fit bounds after adding multiple markers

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am using this piece of code to display map markers pulled from a MySQL database using leaflet js on an open street map, but the map bounds are obviously hard coded at the top (with setView), and I have no idea how to set the bounds to include all iterated markers from the database. Can anyone help? I'm guessing I need to keep an array of the markers and update the bounds based on that?

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer( 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 18,
          attribution: '<a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a> | &copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        $( document ).ready(function() {
          addCompanies();
        });

        function addCompanies() {
          for(var i=0; i<companies.length; i++) {
            var marker = L.marker( [companies[i]['latitude'], companies[i]['longitude']]).addTo(map);
            marker.bindPopup( "<b>" + companies[i]['company']+"</b><br>Details:" + companies[i]['details'] + "<br />Telephone: " + companies[i]['telephone']);
          }
        }

        var companies = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($companies) ?>' );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a featuregroup, it's like a layergroup but better.

Something like this might help.

```
var  myFGMarker = new L.FeatureGroup();
marker = L.marker(lat_lng);
myFGMarker.addLayer(marker);
myFGMarker.addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(myFGMarker.getBounds());
```

Answer (score 7):

You can instantiate a [`LatLngBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#latlngbounds) object and then [`extend()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#latlngbounds-extend) it with the coordinates of the companies. After adding the markers you can call [`map.fitBounds(<LatLngBounds>)`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-fitbounds).

```js
function addCompanies() {
  var bounds = L.latLngBounds() // Instantiate LatLngBounds object
  for (let c of companies) {
    let lat_lng = [c.latitude, c.longitude]
    var marker = L.marker(lat_lng).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup( `<b>${c.company}</b><br>Details:${c.details}<br />Telephone: ${c.telephone}`)
    bounds.extend(lat_lng)      // Extend LatLngBounds with coordinates
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds)
}
```

PS.: I enhanced your code with the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for better readability.
PPS.: Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates the logic of this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/7cavur9o/27/